# Problems with image alignment in table cells

Tags: html, css

I've got a table with about 45 images and some captions underneath the images. What I'm having trouble with is having each image align properly when the image is followed by a large text caption (see 4.jpg's caption). When there's more than one line of text, the image at the top gets slightly pushed above the other images in the row. I'm having trouble figuring out exactly why this is.

Here's the first row of table elements:

```
<table>
    <tr>
    <td><a href="photos/1.jpg" title="354 Address Way"><img src="photos/1_t.jpg" width="72" height="72" alt="" /></a>House</td>
    <td><a href="photos/2.jpg" title="354 Address Way"><img src="photos/2_t.jpg" width="72" height="72" alt="" /></a>House</td>
    <td><a href="photos/3.jpg" title="Foyer"><img src="photos/3_t.jpg" width="72" height="72" alt="" /></a>Foyer</td>
    <td><a href="photos/4.jpg" title="Family Room with small fireplace"><img src="photos/4_t.jpg" width="72" height="72" alt="" /></a>Family Room with small Fireplace</td>
    <td><a href="photos/5.jpg" title="Family Room 2"><img src="photos/5_t.jpg" width="72" height="72" alt="" /></a>Family Room 2</td>
    </tr>
```

Table CSS:

```
table {
    width: 570px;
    font-size: .5em;
    text-align: center;
}

table td {
    width: 128px;
    padding: 0px 10px 0px 10px;
}

table img {
    border: 5px solid #3e3e3e;
    border-width: 2px 2px 2px;
}

table a:hover img {
    border: 5px solid #fff;
    border-width: 2px 2px 2px;
    border-color: #8f8f8f;
    color: #fff;
}
```

I'd just like the images to line up uniformly regardless of the length of the captions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a `vertical-align:top` rule to your table cells. The default value is [baseline](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/vertical-align) however you want the value to be set to top.

```
table td {
    width: 128px;
    padding: 0px 10px 0px 10px;
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/N8zSe/)**

Answer (score 2):

Table cells will vertically align to the middle by default.  Just set them to `vertical-align: top`, possibly with some additional padding.

http://jsfiddle.net/LBb6B/